# Horizontal Swiping to make a layout visible with animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-view

I am working in an android application and I want to make a part of my layout visible and invisible when swiping with an animation effect.

This is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hiddenLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.7"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

By default the layout named "hiddenLayout" visibility is gone. But when I swipe from the left to right it should come to visible with an animation effect just like ViewPager. And its visibility should be gone the swipe in opposite direction.

How can I implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Your activity should implement   GestureDetector.OnGestureListener
You can handle the visibility of the hidden layout inside this method-

```
 @Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, 
        float velocityX, float velocityY) {

    boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

finally add animations for the view..

Comment: Is it possible with view pager  ?

Comment: Actually this is a kind of work around for getting a view pager like effect without using one.